# Draggable Bar Chart using Chart.js in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, chart.js, qualtrics

I am trying to do a draggle bar chart using JavaScript in Qualtrics (survey platform), with Chart.js and the dragData plugin. I see the chart perfectly in the mouse turns into a hand when I put it in the bar (as it should be), but the bars are not draggable. I don't know what the problem could be. Here are the steps:

1. In Qualtrics, in the header, in look and feel, (html form) I write:

```html
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-dragdata@latest/dist/chartjs-plugin-dragdata.min.js"></script>
```

2. In the question where I want the graph to appear, in html mode:

```html
<canvas height="400" id="myChart" width="400">&nbsp;</canvas>
```

3. The javascript code in the questions is:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [
                'Africa',
                'Asia',
                'Europe',
                'Latin America',
                'North America',
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Population (millions)',
                    backgroundColor: [
                        '#3e95cd',
                        '#8e5ea2',
                        '#3cba9f',
                        '#e8c3b9',
                        '#c45850',
                    ],
                    data: [2478, 5267, 734, 784, 433],
                },
            ],
        },

        options: {
            dragData: true,
            dragDataRound: 1,
            dragOptions: {
                showTooltip: true,
            },
            onDragStart: function(e, element) {
                // console.log(e)
            },
            onDrag: function(e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
                e.target.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
                // console.log(datasetIndex, index, value)
            },
            onDragEnd: function(e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
                e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
                // console.log(datasetIndex, index, value)
            },
            hover: {
                onHover: function(e) {
                    const point = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
                    if (point.length) e.target.style.cursor = 'grab';
                    else e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
                },
            },

            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            max: 6000,
                            min: 0,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    });
});
```

It is weird that I cannot drag the bars. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the `console.log` working? Is there any other errors in the console?

Comment: I am not using the console.log, and there are no errors showing up. I took a demo source code from https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragdata (see Bar-Simple Bar example) and adapted couple of lines to Qualtrics. I am very new to java, maybe I should change some other things in the code, but I cannot figure out what. As said before, the mouse becomes a "hand" when touching the bars, but I cannot drag the bars. Thank you!